# How to increase the label and cell size on clicking a button in a TableViewCell.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to expand the cell size after clicking a seeMoreBtn on cell.

The label and cells have varying length, but their is a constraint in size of label.

When a status is too big, I added a seeMoreBtn, after clicking on see more the remaining text will be shown below, then how to increase the label and cell size.

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
    {


        NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(300.0f, 150.0f);
        CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

        CGFloat height1 = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);
        return height1 + (40.0f);
        }
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell-%d",indexPath.row];

        cell=[tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        int lbltag = 1000;

        label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [label setMinimumScaleFactor:14.0f];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
        NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [label setText:text];
        label.tag = lbltag;
        [cell addSubview:label];

        CGSize constraint1=CGSizeMake(300.0f, 150.0f);
        CGSize size1=[text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


        [label setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 300.0f, MAX(size1.height, 44.0f))];

        int countText=text.length;

        if (countText>=350) {
            seeMoreBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [seeMoreBtn setTitle:@"See More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            seeMoreBtn.frame=CGRectMake(220.0f, MAX(size1.height, 44.0f)-10, 80.0f, 20.0f);
            seeMoreBtn.tag=indexPath.row ;
              [seeMoreBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(increaseSize:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell addSubview:seeMoreBtn];            
        }
        return cell;
    }

    -(void)increaseSize:(UIButton *)sender{
//What to write here that can adjust the label and cell size

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better, if you subclass the UITableViewCell and use the layoutSubviews to adjust when you adjust the size of the cell.

```
//In SMTableViewCell.h

@interface SMTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *seeMoreButton;

//SMTableViewCell.m

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect labelFrame = self.statusLabel.frame;
    labelFrame.size.height = self.frame.size.height - 55.0f;
    self.statusLabel.frame = labelFrame;

    CGRect buttonFrame = self.seeMoreButton.frame;
    buttonFrame.origin.y = labelFrame.origin.y+labelFrame.size.height+10.0f;
    self.seeMoreButton.frame = buttonFrame;
}
```

Keep an array to store the selectedIndexPaths:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedIndexPaths;
```

Calculate the height of the cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    BOOL isSelected = [self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];

    CGFloat maxHeight = MAXFLOAT;
    CGFloat minHeight = 40.0f;

    CGFloat constrainHeight = isSelected?maxHeight:minHeight;
    CGFloat constrainWidth  = tableView.frame.size.width - 20.0f;

    NSString *text       = self.items[indexPath.row];
    CGSize constrainSize = CGSizeMake(constrainWidth, constrainHeight);
    CGSize labelSize     = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]
                            constrainedToSize:constrainSize
                                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

    return MAX(labelSize.height+75, 100.0f);

}
```

Initialize custom Show more TableViewCell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    SMTableViewCell *cell= (SMTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([SMTableViewCell class])
                                             owner:nil
                                           options:nil] lastObject];
    }

    BOOL isSelected = [self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];
    cell.statusLabel.numberOfLines = isSelected?0:2;

    NSString *text = self.items[indexPath.row];
    cell.statusLabel.text = text;


    NSString *buttonTitle = isSelected?@"See Less":@"See More";
    [cell.seeMoreButton setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.seeMoreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(seeMoreButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.seeMoreButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Button click event method:

```
- (void)seeMoreButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
    [self addOrRemoveSelectedIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)addOrRemoveSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.selectedIndexPaths) {
        self.selectedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    }

    BOOL containsIndexPath = [self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];

    if (containsIndexPath) {
        [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    }else{
        [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

Same Event is given if the cell is selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self addOrRemoveSelectedIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Sample [Demo project link.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/SeeMoreCell_V1.0.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Add a property like:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *enlargedIndexPaths;
```

Initialize it to an empty array.  Implement the table view delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return ([self.enlargedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])? 88.0 : 44.0;
}
```

Then in increaseSize:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = sender.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathFoCell:cell];
[self.enlargedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];

// do you want to enlarge more than one at a time?  You can remove index paths 
// here, too.  Just reload them below
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:self.enlargedIndexPaths] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the idea is to change the cells height, based on a value you set for the cell.
You can have an NSArray, where you just mark for all cells a value: isExpanded (true or false).

To recap, create an NSMutableArray that will store the cell state (expanded or not):

```
NSMutableArray *cellState;
```

init the array and fill it with zeros for all your UITableView items Array.
When the cell is expanded, set the cellState objectAtIndex value from 0 to 1 (marking it as expanded).

Then reload that cell:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

and modify the `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` function to return a bigger value if the cell is expanded...

That's it!