# How to increase/decrease TableView cell height on click

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to increase the cell height of a tableview along with the row height on row click.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: you can refer this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585053/how-to-increase-the-label-and-cell-size-on-clicking-on-a-button-on-a-cell

Answer (score 0):

I found this some times ago, but I can't manage to make it works with "big" content
http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/14/iphone-uitableview-with-animated-expanding-cells/